# c# app sql connection authorization check

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, security

I have a C# application which uses sql database on sqlexpress. My client will use on his/her computer, so I am concerned about database security. So I have following questions:

1- Should I use Windows Authorization on SQLEXPRESS or SQL Authorization? If I use WA, what if someone (who has a reach Windows Applications accidently, the computer will be in a school campus) reaches the data file and manipulate data (using SSMS maybe?)

2- I also tried to write a trigger on tables which stores sensitive data. My concern is not data reading, but manipulating is; such as insert, update and delete. I tried to use temporary tables (defined by c# application that has some hashed data), the trigger had to check if table exists and hashed data was correct. But c# application cannot reach temporary table even created by itself.

I tried EFS on Windows, but anyone can reach Windows grants, can deactivate EFS on database file. TDE is out of question also, because of SQL version.

The question is how can I check (or trigger check) whether database connection was made by .net applicaton? Is there any better efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved it.

1- I realized that, I can use Windows Authorization but, to prevent data manipulaton beyond the application; giving minimal permissions to Windows user is better way to protect data.

2- Also realized that, I can use tempdb database to create permanent temporary tables. This solves my problem about temporary tables.http://jayeshsorathia.blogspot.com.tr/2012/03/beginning-sql-difference-between-local.html

Thanks for reading.